# MassTransit Mediator: Payload added by Send/Publish not found in ConsumeContext

Tags: masstransit

I'm using MassTransit mediator to Send/Post messages to my consumers, however I'd like to get some metadata delivered to the consumers as a payload, i.e.

```
await mediator.Publish(message, ctx => ctx.GetOrAddPayload(() => metadata));
```

I've looked into MassTransit's code and it seems the payloads from `MessageSendContext<T>` are not copied to `MediatorReceiveContext<T>`

So my question is if it is by design or it was somehow overlooked passing the payloads to `MediatorReceiveContext<T>` .ctor as it has a parameter `params object[] payloads` which might perfectly do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design, as coupling between the producer and consumer would introduce inconsistent expectations since payloads are not transferred between producers and consumers with buses. If you need to pass data to a consumer, it should be done using headers.